# Autoadjusting height of <div> with two elements in it

Tags: html, css

This is probably easily answered by those who know coding properly. I am pretty much self-learned so far and only have 3-4 hours of coding in HTML and CSS behnd me.

I made a  container and put in two more  containers in it. A basic h2+p as a sort of intro section, and another h2+ul+p section as an about-me section.

I wanted the two  inside another  since I wanted the parent  to have a background image that stretches behind both of the other  containers.

However, when I am doing this the second child  is stretching outside the boundaries of the parent  container. The first (leftmost) child  and parent  are aligned on the height. But I am struggling to understand why the parent  doesn't adjust the height so it will contain the full height of the second child  as well.

I've added a border around each  so you can see it easier. You see the border of the parent  between the two child .

http://imageshack.com/a/img745/8052/7Z4yGO.png

```
    <!-- the HTML code -->
    <div id="midSection">
        <div id="introPara">
            <h2>Introduction</h2>
            <p> ---- snipped out ---- </p>
        </div>
        <div id="bioInfo">
            <h3>About me</h3>
            <ul id="bioInfoList">
                <li>Name: Roger</li>
                <li>Nicks: Red Fox Four & Ghroznak</li>
                <li>From: Norway</li>
            </ul>
            <p> ---- snipped out ---- </p>
        </div>
    </div>


/* CSS styling */
#midSection {               /* This is the parent div */
border: solid 1px;
height: 0 auto;
clear: right;
}
#introPara {                 /* Left side intro div */
border: solid 1px;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
width: 60%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
#bioInfo {                  /* Right side about div */
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
border: solid 1px;
width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
float: right;
clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you float a container its parent does not consider its height.You have given `float:right` on 2nd container that's why  the parent is not considering its height and goes only till 1st child container height.

**#Original Problem Fix-** Add a container after 2nd child that clears the float so that parent container takes full height.

```
  <div style="clear:both;">
```

Js fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9a0cep55/1/

**#2nd Problem that i can see -** Even after this your layout will break when width of window is reduced as you have hard coded width of 2nd container to 400px.

When you re-size window to smaller size the 2nd container will wrap below 1st, my  guess you don't want that.

I will recommend that you give 2nd container width also in percentage as width:40% and add style `'box-sizing: border-box;'` on both containers so that borders and padding becomes part of width.

**JS Fiddle Demo** :http://jsfiddle.net/jr5bnLef **( This layout will not break at  any window size)**

Comment: Also i will recommend that you give 2nd container width also in percentage like width:40% and add style 'box-sizing: border-box;' on both containers so that borders and padding becomes part of width. JS Fiddle Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/jr5bnLef/

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly how I wanted it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use clear it will fix the issue

check the  [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/9c8ff4fm/)

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}

<div class="clear"></div>
```

**edit**

changed fixed width to %

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/9c8ff4fm/1/)

Comment: @Roger: Even after this fix the layout will break on re-sizing window to smaller size as 2nd container has hard coded width. To fix that problem see below solution